# How should I configure Typescript to allow the intersection of globals supported by Node and the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, browser

I'm writing a library that must work in both Node and the browser. How can I configure Typescript to expose *only* the globals that are common to both Node and the browser?

For instance, `Buffer` is only supported by Node, not the browser. I want the typechecker to consider this an error.

```
Buffer.from(/* ... */); // ERROR; only supported in Node
^^^^^^
```

On the other hand, `setTimeout` is common to both, so I want this to pass typechecking.

```
setTimeout(() => { /* ... */ }, 1000); // OK; common to both
```

Here's an assortment of other globals and how I would like Typescript to treat them.

```
const a = new AbortController(); // OK; common to both
console.log(/* ... */); // OK; common to both
const u = new Uint8Array(/* ... */); // OK; common to both

process.env.NODE_ENV; // ERROR; not available in browser
__dirname; // ERROR; not available in browser
window.navigator; // ERROR; not available in Node
```